# Unknown option "--enable-x11grab" when installing ffmpeg on centos (6.8)

Tags: image, centos

I am trying to install ffmpeg on a centos (6.8) machine.
Specifically I have done the following:

```
sudo yum install yasm-devel libtheora-devel libvorbis-devel libX11-devel cmake gtk2-devel

git clone http://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis  --enable-libx264  --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-pic
```

The last line gives:

```
Unknown option "--enable-x11grab".
```

I did not find refernce tho this issue on a centos machine online.

How could this be resolved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue with a couple colleagues, and we found that the `--enable-x11grab` option was deprecated in favor of `--enable-libxcb`.

In addition to changing the `./configure` line, you'll likely need to update the ffmpeg command you're using to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

You could also downgrade if you must use that option.

After you clone, use an older commit that supported it, cd into the directory and do something like

```
git fetch origin 719c15aa9ad6983200b78e5dbc17443f649c8af9
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Then run your `./configure`

But following the previous advice to stay current is advised.